# How to concate fields without using CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason, I cannot combine the firstname and lastname from a sql table.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, firstname + ' ' + lastname as fullname from students;
```

For some reason it is showing in the result "0" for each row under fullname, however the firstname and lastname columns are populated as normal.

Please help.
***Please note, I do not want to use CONCAT() function

Screenshot here:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHFMm.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: ANSI SQL has `||` for concatenation.

Comment: Post the table schema.

Comment: By the way, why not using concat ?

Comment: @AxelH they are using concat in the duplicate

Comment: *"they are using concat in the duplicate"* and they are also mentioning `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` SQL mode in MySQL which allows the ANSI SQL string concatenation (`||`) operator @Cid which jarth also mentioned

Comment: Some answers need to be edited to add details on how to use `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`. There is links, but links may die. There is comment, but some don't read them

Comment: *"Some answers need to be edited to add details on how to use PIPES_AS_CONCAT"* Also some old "unsafe" answers or tutorials should also be removed from the internet @Cid .. You can't avoid these things..

Comment: @RaymondNijland good luck removing W3School :-)

Comment: *"good luck removing W3School"* Why whats wrong with it....?? @Cib i think if i turn around and ask what is correct about it you done faster :-)

Comment: I found another duplicate question that had an answer showing use of `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to add two strings.  That doesn't make sense.  Although some (well, really one, given that SQL Server is based on Sybase) database overloads `+` to mean string concatenation, the proper way to do it is either:

```
concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname
```

or as I prefer because it handles `NULL` values cleanly:

```
concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) as fullname
```

or in a database that supports ISO/ANSI operators:

```
(firstname || ' ' || lastname ) as fullname
```

This doesn't work in MySQL, unless you have set the mode `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)).

In MySQL, you will get `0`, because `+` is treated as addition and the two strings are (silently) converted to numbers, based on leading digits.  Because both start with non-digits, they are both converted to `0`.

Comment: *"well, really one"* by curiosity, which one?

Comment: @Cid, could  be Sybase.

Comment: @Cid I think [SQL Server uses + for concatenation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1818d48c4945f92a221c715ddfc1a480).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you

Comment: yes @RaymondNijland

Comment: still seeing 0 in the result....

Comment: And i do not want to use concat

Comment: @Bill . . . If you don't want to use `concat()`, switch to a database that uses your operator of preference.  MySQL concatenates strings with `concat()`.

Comment: IIRC, Microsoft Access also uses `+` for string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but maybe your SQL version uses `||` for the concatenation operator:

```
SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname,
    firstname || ' ' || lastname AS fullname
FROM students;
```

The reason you are seeing zero could perhaps be due to that the database is casting the string columns to numbers, to make the `+` operator make sense.